# Powershell Apply variable to column results for later use

Tags: powershell, vpn, gpo

I've been working on a way to simplify our drive mapping for users with VPN access.

I have a little bit of PS script that gets me a table that i would then like to assign each column a variable and user those variables to map drives.

Here is my script:

```
       $GPO = Get-GPO -All

    foreach ($Policy in $GPO)
    {       
        $GPOID = $Policy.Id
        $GPODom = $Policy.DomainName
        $GPODisp = $Policy.DisplayName

        if (Test-Path "\\$($GPODom)\SYSVOL\$($GPODom)\Policies\{$($GPOID)}\User\Preferences\Drives\Drives.xml")
             {
             [xml]$DriveXML = Get-Content "\\$($GPODom)\SYSVOL\$($GPODom)\Policies\{$($GPOID)}\User\Preferences\Drives\Drives.xml"

                foreach ( $drivemap in $DriveXML.Drives.Drive )

                  {New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                Letter = $drivemap.Properties.Letter + ":"
                                Path = $drivemap.Properties.Path
                                Name = $drivemap.Properties.label

                                }}}}
```

Here is are my results:

```
Letter             Path                                Name
-----------        ---------                           ----------                             
S:                 \\share\Share                       Share                                  
X:                 \\share1\IT Private                 IT Private                             
I:                 \\share3\IT Department              IT Department                          
F:                 \\sahre4\Public                     Public                                 
W:                 \\share5\EmployeeReference          Emplyee                      
R:                 \\sahre5\Reports                    Reports
```

At this point i'm needing to set each column as a variable so i can map these drives for the users.

```
$l = driveletter
$p = drivepath
$n = drivelabel
New-PSDrive -Name $l -root $p
```

Not sure if i'm on the right track here.  Is it a couple of nested foreach statements?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($row in $results) {
    New-PSDrive -Name $row.Letter -root $row.Path -Description $row.name    
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.